# How to combine private git pod AND maximum pod version

Tags: ios, cocoapods, podfile

I'm trying to set a maximum pod version into my 'Podfile', like AFNetworking does:

```
pod 'AFNetworking', '~> 2.0'
```

But I'm using a private repository so I also need to specify the git repository:

```
pod 'AFNetworking', :git => 'https://github.com/gowalla/AFNetworking.git'
```

The cocoapods Guide: https://guides.cocoapods.org/using/the-podfile.html examples show how to use a specific branch, tag or commit:

```
pod 'AFNetworking', :git => 'https://github.com/gowalla/AFNetworking.git', :branch => 'dev'

pod 'AFNetworking', :git => 'https://github.com/gowalla/AFNetworking.git', :tag => '0.7.0'

pod 'AFNetworking', :git => 'https://github.com/gowalla/AFNetworking.git', :commit => '082f8319af'
```

But no maximum pod version.

**How can I combine the private git repository AND a maximum pod version?**

Answer (score 1):

When using a podspec from the root of a repository (i.e, when you put `:git` in your Podfile), CocoaPods will be using the podspec within the root of that repository. A podspec will have a fixed version number attached, therefore there is no such thing as a "maximum" version, there is only, one fixed version.

If instead, you would like to publish a variety of versions of your private Pod, you could include the various versions as separate pod specs within a pod spec repository, take a look at the [CocoaPods guide on private spec repositories](https://guides.cocoapods.org/making/private-cocoapods.html).

Comment: So what the '~> 2.0' stand for into my project podfile if it automatically uses the podspec present at the root of the AFNetworking git repository?

Ok, I think I understand, my private repository (I already have one) link to my Pods git repos which uses the podspecs to know the actual pod version to use.